# Sending email from android application to user email

Tags: android

when I try to send email from android application to user email

my application display exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

my code is:

```
        Mail m = new Mail("mbrm.orion@gmail.com", "*******************");
        String[] toArr = { em };
        m.setTo(toArr);
        m.setFrom("mbrm.yu@gmail.com");
        m.setSubject("[MBRM Orion] Current location of phone: " + pn);
        m.setBody(text);
        try {
            if (m.send()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                        "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);// .show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Email was not sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }
```

can any one help me please

LogCat is:

```
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423): Could not send email
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423): java.lang.NullPointerException: value == null
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:367)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at com.example.MBRMOrion.Mail._setProperties(Mail.java:148)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at com.example.MBRMOrion.Mail.send(Mail.java:89)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at com.example.MBRMOrion.GPS.SendingEmail(GPS.java:637)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at com.example.MBRMOrion.GPS$8$1.run(GPS.java:604)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-16 13:22:55.955: E/MailApp(6423):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: read your stacktrace.

Comment: ...and use your debugger. Null Pointer Exceptions are easy to fix yourself. Set a breakpoint, step through and watch your variables as you go.

Comment: Where are the "em", "pn" and "text" definitions?

Comment: add logcat to qusetion

Answer (score 1):

probably variables 'em' or 'text' or 'pn' are not initialized.Have you stored values in them or they are null ?
You can also use an intent to send email using default email app:

```
                Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"example@dev.com"});
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose Messaging app:"));
```